# Google Security Command Center - how logging Anomaly Detection events?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Guys, could you clarify the question about logging settings for Anomaly Detection events in Google Security Command Center?

I am using Google Security Command Center. I have configured Event Threat Detection logging for all of my projects, activated all rules and I can see Threat Detection events in Stackdriver Logging (type of resource - Threat Detector).
But how can I configure the same feature for Anomaly Detection events? There is no documentation about logging settings, only the description of features. I can assume that Anomaly Detection events will be also sent into Stackdriver, I mean that the setting for Threat detection events and Anomaly Detection events are the same, but I am not sure.
The question about the logging settings for Container Threat Detection events also remains open, also there is no documentation about logging settings...

https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-security-sources#anomaly_detection

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the documentation **you're able to configure logging for Event Threat Detection and Container Threat Detection** ([built-in services](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-configure-security-command-center#built-in_services) are part of Security Command Center). Have a look at the article [Configuring Security Command Center](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-configure-security-command-center):

> Configure Security Command Center, including adding security sources,
> managing which sources apply to which resources, and setting up
> logging for Event Threat Detection and Container Threat Detection.

and at the [Sinks](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-configure-security-command-center#sinks) section:

> **On the Sinks tab, you set up logging for Event Threat Detection and
> Container Threat Detection findings**. Findings are exported to the
> Cloud Logging project you select.
>
> To log findings:
>
> - Click the toggle next to **Log Findings to Stackdriver**.
> - In the **Logging Project** box, select the project that you want to write logs to.

Also, at the documentation [Using Container Threat Detection](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-use-container-threat-detection) section [Reviewing findings](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-use-container-threat-detection#reviewing_findings) you can see:

> When Container Threat Detection generates findings, you can view them
> in Security Command Center, or in Cloud Logging if you have
> [configured Security Command Center sinks](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-configure-security-command-center#sinks) to write to Google
> Cloud's operations suite.

and the same for [Event Threat Detection](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-use-event-threat-detection#reviewing_findings).

On the other hand, [Anomaly Detection](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-security-sources#anomaly_detection) is one of the Google Cloud [security sources](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-configure-security-command-center#gcp-source) integrated with Security Command Center and there's no logging options available for it.

**To solve this issue** you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at the [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and request logging options for Anomaly Detection events.

Comment: Thank you. Will wait for feedback from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Existing documentation for the Anomaly Detection is quite poor. There is only a general description of functionality but the setting steps for the Anomaly Detection and logging are missing.

There is an educational video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n70BdI7apXI and
a publication in Google blog
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/3-steps-to-detect-and-remediate-security-anomalies-with-cloud-anomaly-detection
that may be a "getting starting" guides.

There is a freshly registered issue regardng the gaps in the documentation on the Google Issue tracker. You may keep an eye on it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162820202

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It's awesome, that you created the issue to Google, I hope Google will update the docs and we will find the answer there.